# how to work with parameters in fixes, the fixes are pointers?

Tags: c, matrix, char

I want to generate a 16x16 matrix of characters that contains the letter "o" in upper case, and then save it in a text file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

char generate_matrix(){
    int colum=16,j;
    int rows=16,i;
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<colum;j++){
            matrix[i][j]='O';


        }
    }
    return matrix;    
}
void save(char matrix[16][16]){
    FILE*archivo;
    int i,j;
    char address[]="C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\mat.txt";

    archivo=fopen(addres,"w");
    if(archivo==NULL){
        printf("does not exist");
    }
    else{
        printf("exist");
    }
    for(i=0;i<16;i++){
        for(j=0;j<16;j++){
        fprintf(archivo,"%c\t",matrix[i][j]);   
        }
        fprintf(archivo,"\n");
    }

    fclose(archivo);

}

int main(void){
    generate_matrix();
    save(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

> ERROR
>
> In function 'generate_matrix': error: 'matriz' undeclared (first use in
>   this function)
>                matrix[i][j]='O';
>                ^~~~~~
>   note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once   for each function it appears in matrix.c: In function 'main':
>   error: 'matriz' undeclared (first use in this function)
>        save(matrix);
>                ^~~~~~

please help me, I'm just starting in c
I do not know if the error is because I have to pass the matrix by pointer?
or how can I pass it as a parameter

Comment: Are you trying to allocate memory dynamically for your matrix or create it statically?

Comment: sorry we can't help you much, you don't know the base of C, the best thing you should do is read some book about C before try to code it. we could fix your program but that wouldn't help you.

Comment: The error says `error: 'matriz'` or matri-**z**.  There is no  `matriz` in your code.  Post true code and true error messages

Comment: The error is **not** because of either "have to pass the matrix by pointer"  or parameter.  It is because code uses `matrix` or `matriz` before defining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you never declared "matrix" anywhere. So of course the compiler doesn't know what "matrix" is because you never told it what it is.

Just like how you declared "i" and "j" as "int i,j" and address as "char address[][]". Those lines tell the compiler what those variables are supposed to be. You never declared what "matrix" is supposed to be so the compiler throws a "'matrix' undeclared" error.

You also need to understand scope.

When you declare a variable, it is only valid the scope it is declared in. A variable can have a very narrow scope or it can have a very wide, global scope. One way you can think of scope is in terms of curly braces (these things: {}). Variables declared within curly braces are only valid within the curly braces they were declared in. Once you leave those curly braces, the variable is lost.

One solution you could do would be to declare your "matrix" variable with a global scope. That is, put the declaration at the top of your code outside of any curly braces. This will make the matrix capable of being used by anything within the code.

Although, doing this is typically considered bad practice because using a lot of global variables can get really cluttered really fast and possibly lead to conflicts when incorporating this code into a large project.

Instead, you could declare "matrix" within the "generate_matrix()" function as well as the "main()" function. You could also pass in the array representing the matrix defined within the "main()" function into the "generate_matrix()" function. The "generate_matrix()" function could then modify that matrix. This will make it so that the matrix declared within "main()" is the same matrix that "generate_matrix()" is modifying.

I notice you say "I have to pass the matrix by pointer". You are using an array to represent your matrix, and arrays ARE pointers. When you say something like "char matrix[16][16]", the keyword "matrix" is simply a memory address pointing to where the data for this array is stored. Saying something like "matrix[i][j]" is simply deferencing that pointer using "i" and "j" to calculate the offset.

Since arrays are just pointers, so you aren't copying the matrix values when you pass it into a function. You are copying the value of the pointer, which points to where your array is in memory. So if you pass in a matrix to a function and then modify that matrix, you will be modifying the same matrix that was passed into it, not a copy of it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//Returns nothing because it modifies the matrix passed into it
void generate_matrix(char matrix[16][16]) {
    int colum=16,j;
    int rows=16,i;
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<colum;j++) {
            matrix[i][j]='O';
        }
    }   
}
void save(char matrix[16][16]) {
    FILE*archivo;
    int i,j;
    char address[]="mat.txt";

    archivo=fopen(address,"w");
    if(archivo==NULL) {
        printf("does not exist");
    }
    else {
        printf("exist");
    }
    for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<16;j++) {
        fprintf(archivo,"%c\t",matrix[i][j]);   
        }
        fprintf(archivo,"\n");
    }

    fclose(archivo);

}

int main(void) {
    char matrix[16][16]; //matrix initially declared here
    generate_matrix(matrix); //modify that matrix
    save(matrix); //save it

    return 0;
}
```

You can see the changes I made. I made it so "generate_matrix()" doesn't return anything anymore. Instead, you pass an array into it and it modifies that array. So that allows us to declare the array underneath "main()", pass it into "generate_matrix()" to get modified, then pass it again into "save()".

I also removed "conio.h". That's not part of C standard and is never used by your program. It's not good practice to include libraries that are platform-specific that are unnecessary, because that makes your code unnecessarily unportable.

Finally, I fixed your typo where you referred to "address" as "addres". I also changed your path to save the file because I am not on Windows so I couldn't test the program with that path.